# How to convert 32+ bit number (38bit) into a string on a 32bit system, smartly in C

Tags: c

How would you go about turning a 38bit number into a string if the largest data format available is 32bit?

The decimal representation is needed, the string is needed so as to save the number into a csv file.

The question is complete "as is", there is no need to look for the perceived true intention of the question elsewhere.

Comment: Where/how is your 38bit number stored or represented before you transform it?

Comment: And please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: In a byte array as 5 bytes.

Comment: I cannot imagine any clever way, so I would try the dumb one. First build a library able to process numbers of size 38 bits represented as a 5 bytes array  and convert 32 bits numbers in 38 bits ones (care for endianness...). Then just use the common way of repeated integer division by 10.

Comment: `In a byte array as 5 bytes.` but 5 bytes would be 40 bits (assuming 8-bit bytes), then how are you storing those 38 bits? Would they be aligned to the most or least significnat bit, or somewhere in-between?

Comment: In general, you can see the 5 bytes as digits of a base-256 number. So your task is to divide a base-256 number with 5 digits by 10. There are algorithms for a division with arbitrary base, for example provided here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Algorithm_for_arbitrary_base

Comment: It's exactly 38bits as it is the ID of a FDX-B RFID transponder.

Comment: What system are you building on and what system are you running on that prevents you from using the `int64_t` datatype? (`#include <stdint.h>`)

Comment: What output format?  Hex?  Decimal?  Since it's an RFID transponder, if you can use hex output it's easy - just make sure you zero-pad the lower 32 bits when you convert it to hex, then concatenate the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to work. It uses a static array to store the results, so you'll need to arrange for these to be copied elsewhere if you don't want them to be clobbered by the next call.

The algorithm is simple enough. It just uses long division to divide the number by 10 repeatedly, and uses the remainder at each iteration to build the text output. I'm assuming the input consists of an array of 5 bytes in big-endian order. You can easily change this to work with larger numbers by changing the value of `BIG_WORD_LENGTH`. I should also point out that this function won't work with negative numbers at all. You can speed it up a bit by breaking out of the main loop when n reaches zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BIG_WORD_LENGTH 5

// Length of output is at most ceil(BIG_WORD_LENGTH * log(256) / log(10))
// The following is a slight overestimate, but close enough
#define BIG_WORD_STRLEN (3 + (BIG_WORD_LENGTH) * 5 / 2)

typedef uint8_t big_word[BIG_WORD_LENGTH];

char *big_word_2_str(big_word num) {
    // Make a local copy of the number
    big_word n;
    for (int i=0; i<BIG_WORD_LENGTH; i++) {
        n[i] = num[i];
    }

    // Result goes here
    static char result[BIG_WORD_STRLEN];
    int p = BIG_WORD_STRLEN-1;
    result[p--] = '\0';

    // Calculate digits in base 10
    for (int i=1; i<BIG_WORD_STRLEN; i++) {
        int x, tmp = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<BIG_WORD_LENGTH; j++) {
            x = n[j];
            x += tmp << 8;
            tmp = x % 10;
            n[j] = x / 10;
        }
        result[p--] = '0' + tmp;
    }

    // Trim leading zeros
    while (++p < BIG_WORD_STRLEN-2 && result[p] == '0');

    return result + p;
}


// Test:
int main() {
    // 0x492559f64f = 314159265359
    big_word x = { 0x49, 0x25, 0x59, 0xf6, 0x4f };
    puts(big_word_2_str(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you only have 32-bit integers you probably also only have C89. I suggest moving your variables up top.

Comment: That's a good point, but I'll leave the implementation details to the OP. After all, we still don't even know the endianness of this 38-bit number.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//  Treat a 38-bit number as a two-digit number in base 2**32.
typedef struct { uint32_t Digit[2]; } Binary38;


//  Convert a 38-bit binary number to decimal and print it.
static void DoIt(Binary38 x)
{
    //  Use 10**4 as a base.
    static const uint32_t Base = 10000;

    //  Convert the low digit of x to base Base.
    uint32_t t = x.Digit[0];
    uint32_t y0[3] = { t % Base, t / Base % Base, t / Base / Base };

    /*  The high digit of the Binary38, say d, represents d * 2**32.  To
        convert this, we will multiply it, in base Base, twice by 2**16, adding
        the digits that result to our accumulating sum in y0.
    */

    //  Multiply the high digit of x by 2**16 and convert it to base Base.
    t = x.Digit[1] * (1<<16);
    uint32_t y1[2] = { t % Base, t / Base };

    /*  Multiply y1[0] by 2**16, convert it to base Base, and add it to the
        digits from the conversion of the low digit of x (with some possible
        temporary overflow in each digit position, which we will deal with
        later).
    */
    t = y1[0] * (1<<16);
    y0[0] += t % Base;
    y0[1] += t / Base;

    /*  Multiply y1[1] by 2**16, convert it to base Base, and add it to the
        digits from the conversion of the low digit of x (with some possible
        temporary overflow in each digit position, which we will deal with
        later).
    */
    t = y1[1] * (1<<16);
    y0[1] += t % Base;
    y0[2] += t / Base;

    //  Carry the overflows in y0 from digit to digit.
    y0[1] += y0[0] / Base;    y0[0] %= Base;
    y0[2] += y0[1] / Base;    y0[1] %= Base;

    //  Print the result, suppressing leading zeros.
    if (y0[2] == 0)
        if (y0[1] == 0)
            printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", y0[0]);
        else
            printf("%" PRIu32 "%04" PRIu32 "\n", y0[1], y0[0]);
    else
        printf("%" PRIu32 "%04" PRIu32 "%04" PRIu32 "\n", y0[2], y0[1], y0[0]);
}


int main(void)
{
    //  Try the first number with a bit set in the high component.
    DoIt((Binary38) {{0, 1}});

    //  Try the greatest 38-bit number.
    DoIt((Binary38) {{~ (int32_t) 0, 63}});

    //  Try 99999999999.
    DoIt((Binary38) {{0x4876e7ff, 0x17}});

    //  Try 100000000000.
    DoIt((Binary38) {{0x4876e800, 0x17}});

    //  Try 314159265359.
    DoIt((Binary38) {{0x2559f64f, 0x49}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below contains a function named `ulbtoa` that is able to convert a vector of `uint32_t` considering the contents of the vector as an unique "big integer" in little endian order.

The numeric base of the conversion may be specified.

The function uses a small internal buffer to avoid to destroy the contents of the input vector.

It requires as input:

- a char vector to contains the converted number
- the pointer to the vector to be converted
- the number of bits to be used from the vector to convert
- the base in which the number will be converted

The bits contained in the high element of the uint32_t vector shall be compliant with the number of bits indicated in the function parameters, any bits set to 1 above the specified limit may be used in the function result (you might do a little work around into the function to avoid this behaviour).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * ulbtoa(char *n, uint32_t *v, size_t nbit, size_t base);

#define DIGIT_CONVERT(x) ((char)(((x)<10)?('0'+(x)):('A'+(x)-10)))

char * ulbtoa(char *n, uint32_t *v, size_t nbit, size_t base)
{
    size_t idx = ((nbit+7)/8 );
    size_t i=0,p=0;
    uint32_t tmp=0,r=0;
    uint32_t notzero;

    unsigned char buf[128] = {0};
    unsigned char *b=buf;

    if (n==NULL)
        return n;

    if (idx>sizeof(buf)) {
        b=malloc(idx);
    }

    memcpy(b,v,idx);

    n[p]='0';
    do {
        notzero=0;r=0;tmp=0;
        for(i=idx;i>0;) {
            --i;
            tmp = (r << 8) + (uint32_t)b[i];
            r = tmp % base;
            b[i] = (unsigned char)(tmp / base);
            notzero+=(uint32_t)b[i];
        }

        n[p++]=DIGIT_CONVERT(r);
    } while(notzero);

    char *app=(char *)b;

    if (p>1) { // swap
        for(i=0;i<(p>>1);i++) {
            app[0]=n[i];
            n[i]=n[p-i-1];
            n[p-i-1]=app[0];
        }
    }

    n[(p==0)?1:p]=0;

    if (idx>sizeof(buf))
        free(b);

    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t v[2]={0x12345678U,0x9ABC};
    char n[1024];

    printf("HEX: %s\n",ulbtoa(n,v,48,16));
    printf("DEC: %s\n",ulbtoa(n,v,48,10));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your system supports 64-bit (8-byte) numbers(`long long int`?), zero out a 64-bit number, then `memcpy` the five byte number into the low-order five bytes of the 8-byte value. Depending on the endianness of the five-byte number and the endianness of your system you may or may not have to flip bytes around to get everything to match up.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
  {
                                     /* lo           hi */
  unsigned char five_byte_number_1[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  unsigned char five_byte_number_2[5] = {2, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  long long int bigint;

  bigint = 0;

  memcpy(&bigint, five_byte_number_1, sizeof(five_byte_number_1));

  printf("bigint = %lld\n", bigint);

  bigint = 0;

  memcpy(&bigint, five_byte_number_2, sizeof(five_byte_number_2));

  printf("bigint = %lld\n", bigint);
  }
```

This produces the following output:

```
bigint = 21542142465                                                                                                                                                               
bigint = 21542142466
```

Answer (score -2):

Division by 10, if you need it in decimal representation.
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Integer_division_(unsigned)_with_remainder for available algorithms.

An idea is that if you want to convert to string number "237" you should divide 237 at 10, you will get 23 and 7 in the remainder. then you divide 23, and you will get 2, and 3 in the remainder, then you divide 2 by 10, and you will get 0 and 2 in the remainder, now if you write remainders in an opposite order as "string" you will get 237.

Hope this helps.

Also there are libraries available to do such kind of things, like https://github.com/dandclark/BigInt but there are many of them

Comment: The challenge is to divide by 10 if the number in question does not fit into any datatype to which you can apply `/=10` or `%10`...

Comment: you just didn't read the wiki. Binary algorithms, You do not need integers for this. Just a set of bits.

Comment: The section you link to says “In the following code, all values are treated as unsigned integers, not “In the following code, all values are treated as strings of bits.” And answers should include the answers within them. Links are fine for supplementary information but do not serve as the main answer.

Answer (score -3):

Well, here's an idea:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// define Int38 as an array of 2 32-bit ints 
// so: 64 bits in total, do whatever you want
// with the remaining 24 bits... ;-)
typedef uint32_t Int38[2];

// define a macro to create such a number
#define newInt38(X,a,b) Int38 X; X[0]=a; X[1]=b;
#define printPart()             \
    while (tmp!=0) {            \
        printf("%d",tmp%10);    \
        tmp/=10;                \
    }

void printInt38(Int38 x) {
    uint32_t tmp = x[0];
    printPart();
    tmp = x[1];
    printPart();
}

int main(void){
    // set the first 8 bits as 1, the next 32 bits as 2
    newInt38(i, 1, 2);

    // and print it
    printInt38(i);
}
```

Comment: I fear this does not work, because 2^32 isn't dividible by 10 without remainder.

Answer (score -3):

Ok, my idea is to consider that a 38 bit number can't be more than 10^12 - 12 decimal digits, but a 32 bit number would only normally allow 10^9 completely plus some left over capacity.

What would be good is to take your current 2x32bit fields that form a single 38-bit number (or two fields 1x8bit and 4x8bit), and generate 2 new 32-bit fields, that each represent a value no more than 1,000,000,000, where one represents the lower 9 digits and the other represents the upper 3 (or in general more) digits.

You can then choose to printf just the lower number if the upper number is zero, or printf the upper number followed by the lower number zero-filled to 9 places.

So this technique could allow you to print up to 10^18, or slightly less than 2^60 quite easily, but let's concentrate on just the problem at hand - up to 10^12, and optimise for that.

So dividing the lower field by 10^9 is easy. get result and remainder.

Dividing the upper field is more of a pain:   UF * 2^32 / 10^9

But 10^9 = 2^9 * 5^9, so if we are willing to restrict ourselves to 9 bits in the upper word (we only want 6), wqe can divide through by 2^9

The division result is the same as : UF * 2^23 / 5^9

This /is/ solvable in 32bit!

The remainder from UF * 2^23 / 5^9 must be multipled up by the 2^9 that we factored.
The two "division results" can be summed.
The two remainder can be summed, and if they exceed 10^9 then increment the result, and subtract 10^9 from the remainder.

The result is our upper 3 digits, and the remainder forms our lower 9 digits.

You can then choose to printf just the lower number if the upper number is zero, or printf the upper number followed by the lower number zero-filled to 9 places.

Given that there are only 6 bits you want in the upper word, you could simply generate a 64 entry look-up table and avoid doing the math on the upper word at all!

Note that in terms of total work, we are relying on printf to do some of the formatting here, so it will be doing a loop dividing by 10, but it will only be doing this in the 32-bit space, which is relatively easy. We have done a couple of "extra" division steps to break down the 38-bit number, but at no more than twice the cost of generating a middle digit. So in overall efficiency it cost us about the same as printing 14 digits to print 12, and it probably costs us no extra work if you use the 64 entry look-up, though, it then costs in program size.